# Home/hobbyist quant trading - possible to profitable or just an intellectual hobby?

Tags: research, algorithm

I've been researching algorithmic (non discretionary) trading at the several-day to month timescale, i.e. not HFT. I am not interested in voodoo i.e. no technical analysis, I am looking for solid quant type techniques that can have a positive edge at smaller capacities that are interesting to an individual but that a larger fund would ignore.

Question: I always wonder, are people out there actually able to achieve profitable returns using a home algo trading setup? I realize you wouldn't give away your 'secret sauce' but I would be interested in some feedback as to w/not this can work.

If so what classes of strategy do you look at - stat arb? basic portfolio construction? something more exotic? Anyone care to share general experiences?

Much appreciated.

Comment: The *help me develop a strategy* questions are off topic. Read the [FAQ](http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: This is not a discussion forum.  Please only ask answerable questions which have some hope of a reasonably objective "correct" answer.

Comment: I wouldn't see it as a complete off topic. Comparing with institutional investors, amateur traders have another working framework: they have essential transaction costs, they are more risk-averse etc. i.e. there are some theoretical questions behind to be answered (for instance, how does mean-variance portfolio strategy looks like under transaction costs restriction)

Comment: @MaxLi: This site isn't for amateurs. Though, I agree with your statement if you s/amateur/retail, which is what I think you intended.  Your example would be a fine question, but it's much more specific than "can you share your experiences and what types of strategies should I consider?".

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich with "amateur traders" I meant "non-institutional traders", i.e. not necessarily unskilled traders, sorry for being not enough precise. I agree that the question was formulated unprofessionally, and if 4 people voted to close it down, then I'm ok with it.

Answer (score 4):

I do recommend to you the chapter 8 of the Ernest Chan book "Quantitative Trading: How to Build Your Own Algorithmic Trading Business"

The chapter's name is "Conclusion: Can Independent Traders Succeed? "

The conclusion is that yes but I now cant remember very well the chapter...